# Puppet/Ruby: How to use a ruby variable in a bash line?

Tags: ruby, bash, centos, puppet

I have a Nagios NRPE module in my Puppet environment.

In the `nrpe.cfg` template I've configured some `if statements` in order to set specific checks to specific hosts.

Example:

```
<% if @hostname =~ /rs\d+/ -%> 
command[check_smtp]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_smtp -H rs01.company.com -p 25 -e rs01.company.com 
<% end -%>
```

Meaning:
If hostname starts with chars rs followed by a digit then apply the check commands in the `if statement` block.

I want change the check to something like this:

```
command[check_smtp]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_smtp -H @hostname -p 25 -e @hostname
```

But the problem is that `@hostname` is a ruby variable and the check command is written in bash.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @hostname =~ /rs\d+/ -%> 
command[check_smtp]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_smtp -H <%= @hostname -%> -p 25 -e <%= @hostname -%>
<% end -%>
```